# JQuery check if an anchor in list of anchors has two classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Imagine the following list:-

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#" class="class1 class2">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want an if statement to determine if the anchor with class "class1" has a class "class2" or "class3".
The following code doesn't work, but I hope you could understand from it what I need to accomplish.

```
if ($('ul#list li a.class1').hasClass('class2')) {
    alert('It has class2');
} else if ($('ul#list li a.class1').hasClass('class3')) {
    alert('It has class3');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works, your only problem is that your `else if` statement isn't checking the second condition against the same selector

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. It's fixed now. But still, it didn't work. Josh's solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the following, which will return true if the anchor has all 3 classes.

```
$('a.class1.class2.class3').length;
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ax4x0h5/)